# Error 500 after Django upgrate

Tags: python, django, apache

I have Apache2 server on Ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.6 and websites with Django 1.6. Tomorrow I upgrade Django to 1.8.3 by `sudo easy_install --upgrade django`. After that only first website is working. Other sites rise 500 error. This is apache logs

```
[Mon Jul 27 06:25:07.379926 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22488:tid 140625830381440] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 06:25:07.379972 2015] [core:notice] [pid 22488:tid 140625830381440] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 27 11:30:28.661967 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22488:tid 140625830381440] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 27 11:30:29.777150 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14809:tid 140681711728512] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 11:30:29.777224 2015] [core:notice] [pid 14809:tid 140681711728512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 27 11:32:19.185498 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14809:tid 140681711728512] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 27 11:32:20.263081 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15251:tid 140212319471488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 11:32:20.263186 2015] [core:notice] [pid 15251:tid 140212319471488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 08:02:22.246092 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15251:tid 140212319471488] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 08:02:23.297084 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17323:tid 140099360208768] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 08:02:23.297185 2015] [core:notice] [pid 17323:tid 140099360208768] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 08:11:13.768112 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17323:tid 140099360208768] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 08:11:14.881159 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17844:tid 140223468337024] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 08:11:14.881229 2015] [core:notice] [pid 17844:tid 140223468337024] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 09:05:13.986042 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17844:tid 140223468337024] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 09:05:15.076053 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18544:tid 140727691057024] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 09:05:15.076167 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18544:tid 140727691057024] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:24.254449 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18544:tid 140727691057024] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:25.319182 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19105:tid 140677893478272] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:25.319282 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19105:tid 140677893478272] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:45.336099 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19105:tid 140677893478272] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:46.407414 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 09:57:46.407495 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:30.278006 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2a01:4f8:d15:dc0::2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:30.512300 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:30.512326 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:45.286141 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2a01:4f8:d15:dc0::2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:45.392009 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 09:58:45.392031 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 28 10:02:35.249547 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19533:tid 139860213520256] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 28 10:02:36.323445 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20874:tid 139918807410560] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 28 10:02:36.323553 2015] [core:notice] [pid 20874:tid 139918807410560] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And this is wsgi.py file of the project

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thanks for advice!

Comment: What you mean by first website?

Comment: The first website that was deployed on this server. When I doesn't write ServerAlias www.mysecondsite.com, apache redirect on this first site.

Comment: Have you checked if your Django apps actually work both on Django 1.6 and Django 1.8.3? Not everything is compatible.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. It is almost the same Django apps just with CharFields, TextFields and with ListView, DetailView

Comment: As there is no Python exception details in the Apache error log with traceback, the 500 error is likely coming from Django. Enable DEBUG as True in the Django settings file temporarily so you can see in the browser what the error is Django is encountering. BTW, you are using an ancient mod_wsgi version which is something like 20 releases behind. You should consider upgrading.

Comment: DEBUG is True, now i try to upgrade mod_wsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it! It was really Django error. DEBUG was True value in settings.py file  but it still rise 500 error. What was the real error i understand then i type `python manage.py shell`. So it was `The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings`. Thanks everyone!